# Logitech k400 does not detect keypresses

Tags: windows-7, wireless-keyboard

I have been a satisfied user of this keyboard for 3 years, but in the last half year, it is really difficult to work with. I have to hold it in a special position for it to detect the keypresses. Sometimes I type 4-5 letters, recognise there is nothing on the screen, tilt it a bit, and suddenly the letters appear.

I thought it has a connection problem, so I bought an USB extender, and moved the dongle from behind the case to the front. It helped for a bit, but than the bad behavior started again. I bought a new one, it has the same problem.

I usually use it with Win7, but when I tried it with Linux, it behaved the same.

I live in an apartment building, and the number of wifis in range grew recently. They all broadcast in the 2.4 GHz region, and so does the keyboard.
Can it be the reason?

What can I do?

Comment: If the new keyboard gave you the same behavior as the old one, this can only be one of two things.

1: A driver issue
2: A malware issue

Answer (score 0):

Go to the logitech support page for this keyboard and download [the latest driver](http://support.logitech.com/product/wireless-touch-keyboard-k400r#download).

After this, uninstall your driver from your hardware device list, and reinstall it via your newly downloaded drivers, then restart your system.

If this did not work we are most likely dealing with malware, run a full scan with [malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/). If that doesn't fix it either, I've got no real solution.

(It is to be noted that wireless signals can be interrupted by microwaves, and big metal, concrete or brick obstacles (like walls), if you are in the same room as your computer however with the keyboard, I imagine it should be fine. As long as you are within a 10m range which is the limit for the device. Besides your own wifi I doubt any of the wireless signals around could interrupt your device from your unifying receiver, but if that truly is the case you can try changing the wifi channel in your router settings.)

Answer (score 0):

Things to try - assuming it's not software at issue…

- change the batteries & re-sync the devices - there's usually a button on both you need to press to resync.
- get the receiver away from the case itself, metal reflects.
- Away from the monitor, speakers or any nearby TV etc.
- Try it at different angles [this may be better with an assistant, like trying to fix a 1950's sitcom TV aerial] - one face may be better than the others.
  Some of those dongles can be very directional.